# PosGis and Django-Tenants

Tags: django, postgis

(Using the library django-tenants for tenant separated multi-tenancy) For PostGis support the docs say to add `ORIGINAL_BACKEND = "django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis"`. I have this, however, when I go to create a new tenant I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\cole\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\celery\app\trace.py", line 382, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\cole\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\celery\app\trace.py", line 641, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Cole\Documents\GitHub\Elevate-RA-Django-App\returns_app\apps\tenant_stores\tasks.py", line 28, in create_tenant_task
    tenant.save()
  File "c:\users\cole\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\django_tenants\models.py", line 93, in save
    self.create_schema(check_if_exists=True, verbosity=verbosity)
  File "c:\users\cole\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\django_tenants\models.py", line 143, in create_schema
    verbosity=verbosity)
  File "c:\users\cole\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 141, in call_command
    return command.execute(*args, **defaults)
  File "c:\users\cole\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 335, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "c:\users\cole\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\django_tenants\management\commands\migrate_schemas.py", line 63, in handle
    executor.run_migrations(tenants=tenants)
  File "c:\users\cole\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\django_tenants\migration_executors\standard.py", line 15, in run_migrations
    run_migrations(self.args, self.options, self.codename, schema_name, idx=idx, count=len(tenants))
  File "c:\users\cole\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\django_tenants\migration_executors\base.py", line 34, in run_migrations
    MigrateCommand(stdout=stdout, stderr=stderr).execute(*args, **options)
  File "c:\users\cole\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 335, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "c:\users\cole\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 77, in handle
    connection.prepare_database()
  File "c:\users\cole\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\db\backends\postgis\base.py", line 26, in prepare_database
    cursor.execute("CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS postgis")
  File "c:\users\cole\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "c:\users\cole\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "c:\users\cole\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "c:\users\cole\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "c:\users\cole\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "c:\users\cole\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 83, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "spatial_ref_sys" does not exist
```

The spatial_ref_sys table exists within my public schema. The django.contrib.gis app is in my shared apps.

Any ideas?

Comment: It seems to be caused by `cursor.execute("CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS postgis")` but the search path is set to `SET search_path = return_app_test,public;` (where `return_app_test` is my tenant schema)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be cause by the default PostGis backend, specifically the call to prepare the database for migration, by explicitly setting the search path prior to calling `CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS postgis` I was able to migrate/create a schema by creating a custom DB backend that overrides this behaviour:

```
from django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis.base import (
    DatabaseWrapper as OriginalPostGisDatabaseWrapper,
)
from django_tenants.utils import get_public_schema_name


class DatabaseWrapper(OriginalPostGisDatabaseWrapper):
    """
    This database wrapper explicitly sets the search path when preparing the database, as
    multi-schema environments (like with Django-tenants) can cause issues with the PostGis
    backend.
    """

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.PUBLIC_SCHEMA_NAME = get_public_schema_name()

    def prepare_database(self):
        # Check that postgis extension is installed.
        with self.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute('SET search_path = %s', params=[self.PUBLIC_SCHEMA_NAME])
            cursor.execute("CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS postgis")
```

Then, set your `ORIGINAL_BACKEND` setting to the location of the above DB backend instead of the standard `PostGis` backend.